# Chronological Series of PCI

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I need a chronological series of PCI, to compare different maintenance costs (from different maintenance policies).

The file can be in any format but not limited to: `txt/tsv`, `csv`, `ods`, `xls/xlsx`, and `pdf`.

Comment: Can you explain what PCI means?

Comment: And please [edit] your question titel too. Nobody is going to look at *Help! (from Uruguay)* You should remove everything from your text that is irrelevant to the actual question. [Read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) for more guidance.